# if-statement based function best practice

Tags: ios

i was just writing this simple piece of code:

```
-(void)goToStep:(int)step{
    self.step1.hidden = YES;
    self.step2.hidden = YES;
    self.step3.hidden = YES;
    self.step4.hidden = YES;

    if(step == 1)
        self.step1.hidden = NO;
    if(step == 2)
        self.step2.hidden = NO;
    if(step == 3)
        self.step3.hidden = NO;
    if(step == 4)
        self.step4.hidden = NO;
}
```

now considering what differences writing is like this instead would make, performancewise or other.

```
-(void)goToStep:(int)step{
    if(step == 1){
        self.step1.hidden = NO;
    self.step2.hidden = YES;
    self.step3.hidden = YES;
    self.step4.hidden = YES;
    }
if(step == 2){
        self.step2.hidden = NO;
    self.step1.hidden = YES;
    self.step3.hidden = YES;
    self.step4.hidden = YES;}
    if(step == 3){
        self.step3.hidden = NO;
    self.step2.hidden = YES;
    self.step1.hidden = YES;
    self.step4.hidden = YES;}
    if(step == 4){
        self.step4.hidden = NO;
    self.step2.hidden = YES;
    self.step3.hidden = YES;
    self.step1.hidden = YES;}
}
```

alternatively making a switch, would that do any difference?

What way is better? Thanks

Comment: Who says one way must be better than the other?  Consider what style will make long-term maintenance easier, by not "concealing" logic somehow.

Comment: Hah, ifs without braces, the second example demonstrates very well what weird kind of thing you get if you dont start using braces.

Comment: Hah, I always use braces for multi-line ifs...... Anyway, while editing on-page I mustve missed those in the rush

Comment: @Hot Licks I was merely considering if it had any influence performance wise or any other way.

Comment: Mainly consider what will happen if you come along and add `step5`, or if there is some other logic there, setting titles or such.  Especially when you add such stuff later, certain schemes (especially if missing "unnecessary" braces) can cause nasty errors to be introduced.  (Rarely is performance an issue with this sort of decision.)

Comment: @HotLicks Yes true, but then I guess the only right way would to be use some kind of collection for future management; the answer given would also need to add same code for each new add. Regarding those braces, I never rly get errors due to those; I must admit my posted code was slob by:( thx for your reply

Comment: It's always a balancing act.  Sometimes the right way to go is as simple as possible (serial `if` statements, eg).  Sometimes it's best to invent some sort of collection to hold the settings right from the start (or replace the "simple" scheme with it as soon as the need is becoming obvious).  Or somewhere in-between.  It's one of those things that comes with experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second variant is buggy, it doesn't do what the first one does.

The best way to go is what's most readable (and if it doesn't need redundant logic, the better).

I suggest:

```
-(void)goToStep:(int)step {
    self.step1.hidden = step != 1;
    self.step2.hidden = step != 2;
    self.step3.hidden = step != 3;
    self.step4.hidden = step != 4;
}
```

Or iterate over a collection:

```
NSArray *buttons = @[self.step1, self.step2, self.step3, self.step4];
[buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIButton *button, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    button.hidden = idx != (step - 1);
}];
```

Or over a dictionary with the number as keys... plenty of ways. :)

Comment: Except that your logic is backwards - see my answer.

Comment: @Eiko What is the reasoning for semantics when you do: x = y != 1; compared to "x = !(y==1)". Is it simply just because != is an operator as is * or /, when = is ever only assignment?

Comment: It's all about readability. "!=" is so common that it almost reads like an English word. Putting parentheses around the term is one more thing to think about, then using equal-equal reverses the logic, just to reverse it again. It needs significantly longer to understand and is much easier to err about in a quick glance.

Answer (score 3):

None of them. What you want to do is cover every case completely. Thus:

```
self.step1.hidden = (step != 1);
self.step2.hidden = (step != 2);
// ...
```

Of course, it would be even better if you had an outlet collection or other array so that you could turn `step` directly into an index value to access the desired object.

Comment: I would say I am covering every case in the code i provided. I see why yours look more smooth though. Btw, step1-4 are declared as outlets as well

Answer (score 0):

different approach without `if - else`

```
  // assuming that all steps are hidden by default
  NSArray *steps = @[step1, step2, step3, step4];
  int currentStep = 0;
  step1.hidden = NO;

  - (void)goToStep:(int)step{
    step--; // adjust zero-based index
    if (currentStep != step) {
      steps[currentStep].hidden = YES;
      steps[step].hidden = NO;
      currentStep = step;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example and second example behave differently. Under the second example, steps 2, 3, and 1 will always be set to hidden=YES when the function completes because those last three statements are outside an if-block and will therefore always execute.

The way I usually handle situations like this is to put all 4 views in an array (say we call it 'self.steps'). Then your function becomes:

```
    -(void)goToStep:(int)step {

        for(UIView *stepView in self.steps) {
           [stepView setHidden:YES];
        }

       [[self.steps objectAtIndex:step] setHidden:NO];
    }
```